# system verilog interface with function

Tags: system-verilog

How can I add a function in an interface? I am trying to implement half adder using interface having function to calculate sum and carry.Following is my code for the same. When trying without functions it as running by using complemented lines.

```
module top_ha_interface;   
  ha_interface nh1();   
  ha h1(nh1);   
  ha_tb h2(nh1); 
endmodule 

interface ha_interface;   
  logic sum,c_out;   
  logic a,b;   
  function summ(a,b,output sum,c_out);     
    sum=a^b;     
    c_out=a&b;   
  endfunction   
endinterface 

module ha(ha_interface nh1);   
//  assign nh1.sum=nh1.a^nh1.b;   
//  assign nh1.c_out=nh1.a&nh1.b;   
  nh1.summ(nh1.a,nh1.b);  
endmodule 

module ha_tb(ha_interface nh1);   
  initial   
  begin         
    nh1.a=1'b1;         
    nh1.b=1'b0;     
    #10 $display($time,"ns\t",nh1.sum,nh1.c_out);         
    nh1.a=1'b1;         
    nh1.b=1'b1;     
    #20 $display($time,"ns\t",nh1.sum,nh1.c_out);         
    nh1.a=1'b0;         
    nh1.b=1'b0;     
    #30 $display($time,"ns\t",nh1.sum,nh1.c_out);   
  end 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function is synthesizable, but that must be used, within any procedural block of verilog. (Like always or initial)

> Tasks and void functions are called as statements within procedural
>   blocks

So required modifications in your code :

```
module ha(ha_interface nh1);   
//  assign nh1.sum=nh1.a^nh1.b;   
//  assign nh1.c_out=nh1.a&nh1.b;   
  always @ (*)
    nh1.summ(nh1.a,nh1.b, nh1.sum, nh1.c_out);  
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks
It's working now.
Can you please tell me how can I improve my SV skills?
Is it possible to finish UVM within a month?
I will start working on UVM from tomorrow onward and I study for 12 hours daily.

Comment: @NIKHILARORA : You can read book like "SV For Verification" by Chris Spear, System Verilog LRM. For UVM, you should read "UVM Cookbook" and also you can watch videos on Verification Academy. Btw, if you are convinced with the answer, you can accept my answer, also you can upvote it, if you want.

Comment: [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) is the SystemVerilog LRM. The (Verification Academy)[https://verificationacademy.com/] is a good resource; I'd recommend the video lessons over the UVM Cookbook. Neither are perfect, but I find the the cookbook more OVM oriented (a predecessor methodology) has more confusing subtle typos that make learning more painful.

Comment: @ Greg and Karan: Are you sure that I can finish UVM in a month by studying 12 hours in a day?

Comment: @NIKHILARORA : That noone can assure, how much time a person will take to understand any specific thing. But yeah one month, with dedicated efforts, you can learn many required things of UVM.

Comment: @Karan: Thanks. I have to appear in an interview on 15 March. So I am preparing for that.
Thanks.

Comment: @Greg: Verification academy video tutorials requires high level access and I don't have that. So tell me some other alternative please, preferably video lectures.

Comment: @KaranShah, some content on VA requires a full access account, such as posting on the forums. I'm not sure if the videos are basic access or full access. I believe you can get full access by filling out a surrey in your profile. As for other resources, there is list in my profile.

Comment: Also, focus on the fundamentals for your interview. UVM is too advance if you do not understand the verilog scheduler,  the difference between virtual/automatic/static methods, `@( sensitivity list )` vs `@*` vs `always_comb` vs `always_latch`, ANSI / non-ANSI headers, etc.